# What should a Socket Thread class do

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

```
public class SOCKET_SERVER {

    private JmailHelp JmailHELPER = new JmailHelp();
    static int PORT = 444;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SOCKET_SERVER SERVER = new SOCKET_SERVER();
        SERVER.JmailHELPER.resetONN();
        ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        //ArrayList<SocketStatus> OnlineUsers = new ArrayList<SocketStatus>();

        Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
        //new ServerThread(SOCK).start();
        SocketStatus a = new SocketStatus(SOCK, false);
        //OnlineUsers.add(a);
        //String action = "";
        SERVER.ServerActionsHandler(SERVER, SRVSOCK, SOCK, a);

    }//
}
```

forgive me if what i am giving is not enough don't hesitate to ask more if you can and want to try to help me
Well,
this is my socket server class `ServerActionHandler` is a method i created that takes as "input"(by `BufferedReader`) from the client a string and calls the right methods to serve the client.

for example he wants to login:

1. he(client) sends the string "login"
2. then server takes it as an "input" by the `ServerActionHandler` in a string called action, then recognise the the "login" and then calls the `Acceptlogin` method from the server class
3. Meanwhile client who send the "logi message" is calling the Dologin method from the client class

4.a loop of the `ServerActionsHandle`r ends

5.A new loop starts asking the new action from the Client

my project works for A server and One client
I want to make it working for many clients

also something more I use `JmailHELPER` object 
in almost all the methods of `SOCKET_SERVER` class(eg. login_accept,register_accept...)
in order to call some methods of it's class.

And `SocketStatus` keeps one variable if the certain socket which uses the Server is logged in or not

from what I know i have to make a `ServerThreads` class that extends Threads to handle more than one users.
What is the constructor and the run of that classmethod supposed to do

for example of A `SocketThread` I have this http://www.cdk5.net/ipc/programCode/TCPServer.java

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok,
I know its funny but after a break of two hours I tried to find the solution for 3 minutes and i solved it(thats what i believe for now :P )

At least it is working on my pc for two clients so I will check it tommorow in more than one pc

Anyway I am posting the answer to my problem so that you can see it if you have a common problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SOCKET_SERVER SERVER = new SOCKET_SERVER();
    SERVER.JmailHELPER.resetONN();
    ServerSocket SRVSOCK = new ServerSocket(PORT);

    while (true) {
        Socket SOCK = SRVSOCK.accept();
        SocketStatus a = new SocketStatus(SOCK, false);
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SERVER.ServerActionsHandler(SERVER, SRVSOCK, SOCK, a);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SOCKET_SERVER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                };
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```